# How to prevent records from appending multiple times in a cell in python csv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, twitter

I've been working on retrieving twitter live data where i want to extract out certain fields of a tweet to csv, where one row represents a tweet; the tweetid and the tweet text. Everything works fine until i appended the tweet text to the csv where suddenly a multiple number of tweets gets inserted into a tweet text cell.

**I printed the tweetid, counter and text and it printed out perfectly fine of up to 12000 records per line.**

However, in the csv file, i'm missing out of 200 records due to this problem.  I added a counter to identify and keep track of where i lost the 200 records. I've been stuck for a few hours. Can someone help me identify what is wrong?

**Here's a screenshot of my working csv:**
[image]

**This is the problem:** [image]

**Here is my code:**

```
      with client:
         with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore') as file:
            fw = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
            fw.writerow(['CollectionId', 'Counter', 'Text'])
            print('starting to append data to csv...')
            counter = 0
            print('appending Streaming data...')
            for stream in Streaming:
                streamTime = stream["created_at"]
                parseTime = dateutil.parser.parse(streamTime)

                # CollectionId
                if stream["id_str"]:
                    collectionId = "'" + stream["id_str"] + "'"
                    counter = counter + 1

                    # cleanup text -  to display in a single line
                    streamText = stream["text"]
                    streamText = streamText.split('\n') #remove new lines in text 
                    streamText = " ".join(streamText)
                    streamText = streamText.replace(',', ' ') #replace commas in text
                    #print("{}, {} - {}".format(collectionId, counter, streamText))
            fw.writerow([collectionId, counter, streamText])
        print("Streaming Data has been exported to 'data.csv'")
```

Comment: Is that code all we need to run your program, is it a [mcve]?

Comment: Yes its simplified

Comment: It might be the delimiter?

Comment: If its the delimiter problem, then why there are no issues with most of the tweets?